# Oops, I reopened my own question

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicates, vote-to-reopen

I have a question how [legitimate it is to cast unused spell slots in the moring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198324/is-casting-unused-spells-in-the-morning-legit) before learning new spells. It was closed as a duplicate of if you can [cast spells during a long rest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/42123/does-a-short-combat-or-casting-one-spell-interrupt-a-long-rest). After I edited it, to highlight that the question was different, as it was as much concerned about the narrative appropriateness of the tactic as about if its purely technical legal (it even laid out why I think it should be no issue technically), I hit the reopen button to submit it for review.

However, it appears that my newfound status as a gold answerer for 5e questions changed the result of this action from "Hey, I totally think my questions is fine to ask, can you please, please, pretty please reconsider and reopen it?" to: the question is now reopened again.

I was not aware this would happen (the status just changed this morning), and just want to highlight this here for review. While I of course would be much happier if the question would remain open, I don't want to mis-use the privileges of that status for my own questions.

Comment: Note, you could only do this because it was closed as duplicate. Dupes are a different type of closure that gold tag-badges have special privileges over.

Comment: You did an oops — that is okay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why is this an “oops”?

You intentionally voted to reopen a question, and the system interpreted the vote according to your level of site privilege. The system is working as intended.

Comment: I did not realize it would behave differently that status change just had happened before and I was not aware it would change this behavior

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin You have ascended.

Comment: In this case the outcome seems fine, however the assumption *"my privileges let me do it therefore it's fine"* is not a good precedent. Privileges are earned on the by reputation on the assumption that by the time it is earned, the user has enough experience to know when to apply them appropriately. Typically it is a good idea to use restraint or get a second opinion when using privileges on your own question or a question you have a stake in, as @GroodytheHobgoblin has done here.

Comment: @linksassin I’m of the opinion that if a close/reopen vote isn’t appropriate as a binding vote, it isn’t appropriate as a nonbinding vote. Getting the gold badge shouldn’t change your decision making process.

Comment: If having the gold badge means you are now more careful with your close votes, that means you were too loose before, not that the gold badge changes how you should approach it.

Comment: people can still vote to overturn gold-Groody's vote.

Comment: I don't exactly agree with the stance on voting. A binding vote has different consequences when compared to a non-binding vote. Hedge votes that back up agreement are valid, and some votes where you think that your vote is correct but want more community input on can't be made with a gold badge (chat usually is a good venue to get more pairs of eyes), but are less iffy when it is non-binding.